# Detect Slow Internet in Angular 6+ Application

Tags: performance, angular6, detect

So, I am using angular 6 for my application and with that, I am also using plugins to detect Internet connection but I also want to inform my user that their internet connection is slow or show some message **Slow Internet Connection**.

I have seen all the answers related to this problem. Most of them were explaining about the connectivity of the internet. Only a few explained how to measure slow internet but I didn't like those solutions i.e., using timeout or hitting server with download requests and calculating the speed by dividing size with time taken.

So, I want a more general and reliable solution for this problem and if there is any package for this purpose, please do recommend.

Comment: I am facing an issue related to slow connection. Have you found a proper answer to that matter?

Comment: not yet @malrok44 ...!!!

Comment: I ended just checking for connection on my project, but I found this API which seems standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/downlink  Maybe this can help you ^^